# Save Data to Localstorage and use it to populate fields after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have optin popup of two steps, first step is to capture email and name, when user click submit the data is captured, and another popup appears, the new popup has a form with more fields to get more info, plus email and name field.

what I want to do is to automatically populate the email and name field from first popup and hide them with `display:none` so user can't see them, after submit the data is captured again (all goes to activecampaign).

the two forms works just fine, what is not working is saving the data and calling it when needed

here is the js I'm using

```
jQuery(function($){
  // PART I: Saving user details locally

    $('#arlington-field-submit').on('click', function(){

    // check if the user's browser has localStorage support
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.
        // store the full name in localStorage
        var fullname = document.querySelector("input[name=arlington-name]");
        localStorage.user_name = fullname.value;

        // save the email in localStorage
        var email = document.querySelector("input[name=arlington-email]");
          $("input[name=fullname]").val(localStorage.getItem("server"));
        localStorage.user_email = email.value;

    }
  });

  // PART II: Pre-filling forms forms with locally saved values
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {

    // check if the user has a name field stored 
    if (localStorage.user_name) {
      name_field = document.querySelector("._form input[name=fullname]");
      name_field.value = localStorage.user_name;
    }

    // check if the user has an email field stored
    if (localStorage.user_email) {
      email_field = document.querySelector("._form input[name=email]");
      email_field.value = localStorage.user_email;
    }

    }
});
```

first form html:

```
    <div id="arlington-element-form" class="arlington-element-form arlington-element" data-element="form">
<div id="arlington-form" class="arlington-form arlington-has-name-email arlington-has-buttons">
   <div class="arlington-form-wrap"><input id="arlington-field-comments" name="arlington-comments" type="text" data-selectable="true" data-target="#builder-setting-comments_value" class="arlington-field-comments" placeholder="" value="" style="" autocomplete="off"><input id="arlington-field-name" name="arlington-name" type="text" data-selectable="true" data-target="#builder-setting-name_value" class="arlington-field-name" placeholder="Enter your name here..." value="">
   <input id="arlington-field-email" name="arlington-email" type="email" data-selectable="true" data-target="#builder-setting-email_value" class="arlington-field-email" placeholder="Enter your email address here..." value="" >
 <input id="arlington-field-submit" name="arlington-submit" type="submit" data-selectable="true" data-target="#builder-setting-submit_value" class="arlington-field-submit" value="JOIN NOW" >
   </div>
   <div class="arlington-yesno-wrap">
   <button id="arlington-button-yes" type="button" name="arlington-yes" data-selectable="true" data-target="#builder-setting-yes_value" data-action="form" data-type="yes" class="arlington-button-yes arlington-button-yesno">Submit!</button>
   </div></div></div>
```

second form html:

```
<form method="POST" action="xxxxxx" id="_form_8_" class="_form _form_8 _inline-form _dark" novalidate> <input type="hidden" name="u" value="8" /> <input type="hidden" name="f" value="8" /> <input type="hidden" name="s" /> <input type="hidden" name="c" value="0" /> <input type="hidden" name="m" value="0" /> <input type="hidden" name="act" value="sub" />    <input type="hidden" name="v" value="2" />
    <div class="_form-content">
        <div class="_form_element _x72304349 _full_width "> <label class="_form-label"> Full Name </label>
            <div class="_field-wrapper"> <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Type your name" /> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="_form_element _x10201592 _full_width "> <label class="_form-label"> Email* </label>
            <div class="_field-wrapper"> <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Type your email" required/> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="_form_element _x29901314 _full_width "> <label class="_form-label"> Phone </label>
            <div class="_field-wrapper"> <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Type your phone number" /> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="_button-wrapper _full_width"> <button id="_form_8_submit" class="_submit" type="submit"> Submit </button> </div>
        <div class="_clear-element"> </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery with native JS? Rather than `document.querySelector(".arlington-form");` you could use `$('.arlington-form')`

Comment: At a first glance it should work. What do you notice? Nothing registered in `localStorage`?

Comment: Are you getting an error at all in the console? The line `$(input[name=fullname])` should be `$("input[name=fullname]")`

Comment: Tested: once corrected the error pointed by @WillP., the data is pretty well registered.

Comment: @WillP.  I changed the js code based on your suggestion, there are no errors, and it doesn't seem to be saving anything at all to localStorage

Comment: Have you tried preventing the default submit action on the form? Chances are, the page is navigating before the JS has a chance to run.

Answer (score 0):

Since the input which is being clicked is a submit button, chances are that the page is navigating before the JS within the click handler gets a chance to fire.

Try and replace 
`$('#arlington-field-submit').on('click', function(){`

with:

`$('#_form_8_').on('submit', function(event){`

Then you can prevent the form from actually submitting so your JS can run:

```
$('#_form_8_').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  // Do localStorage stuff
  $(this).submit(); // submit the form normally after localStorage is saved
});
```

Comment: Well, the point of this is to capture the most important data, email and name, then show the other form with more fields, so in case user don't want to fill or decided to close we will still have the email, so I can't use preventDefault, is there any other way around it?

Comment: You could capture the information when the input is blurred `$('input').on('blur', function () {});`

Answer (score -1):

The way you look for elements is wrong, because you forgot quotes wrapping attribute values:

```
var fullname = document.querySelector("input[name=arlington-name]");
```

should be:

```
var fullname = document.querySelector('input[name="arlington-name"]');
```

And so on...

BTW I'm surprised you don't report an error like "An invalid or illegal string was specified".

Comment: Works fine with or without quotes on the attribute value https://jsfiddle.net/wspedgj4/

Comment: @CarlMarkham Oh, I see that you're right! I believed this tolerance had been deprecated from times.

Comment: As @CarlMarkham said, it works fine without quotes, but still, this is not my issue, I think the data is not being saved at all.